# Selenium webdriver: How to delete/flag spam comments on YouTube platform (without API)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, https

I've been trying to flag/report a list of spam comments in a particular YouTube video.

For that I've been using this code on Python, which loads my previous profile so I log in with my account:

```
URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=dvecqwfU6xw&lc=Ugxw_nsUNUor9AUEBGp4AaABAg.9fDfvkgiqtW9fDkE2r6Blm"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
user = pathlib.Path().home()
print(user)

options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/")

driver= webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
driver.get(URL)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

comment_box = '//*[@id="comment"]'
reply_box ='//*[@id="replies"]'

while(True): 
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 200);")
  try:
    reply_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, reply_box)
    print(reply_box.text)
    break
  except:
    pass

# resp = driver.request('POST', 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/flag/get_form?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&prettyPrint=false')
# print(resp.text)

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="button"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

The problem comes with opening the menu, I believe since you have to hover over the 3 dots menu it would then appear as the clickable menu so I never get to open the actual menu to report/flag the comment.

Comment: do you get error or what? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: it seems this page has many `id="button"` and you may have to use better `XPath` to search correct element.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was not to take full Xpath path.... It works perfectly like this, THANKS

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
user = pathlib.Path().home()
print(user)

options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/")
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver= webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
driver.get(URL)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

comment_box = '//*[@id="comment"]'
reply_box ='//*[@id="replies"]'

while(True): 
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 200);")
  try:
    reply_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, reply_box)
    print(reply_box.text)
    break
  except:
    pass

option_button = '/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-comment-thread-renderer[1]/div/ytd-comment-replies-renderer/div[2]/ytd-comment-renderer/div[3]/div[3]/ytd-menu-renderer/yt-icon-button/button'
option_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, option_button)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", option_button)

report_button = '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/tp-yt-iron-dropdown/div/ytd-menu-popup-renderer/tp-yt-paper-listbox/ytd-menu-service-item-renderer/tp-yt-paper-item/yt-formatted-string'
report_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,report_button)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", report_button)

report_button_spam = '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/tp-yt-paper-dialog/yt-report-form-modal-renderer/tp-yt-paper-dialog-scrollable/div/div/yt-options-renderer/div/tp-yt-paper-radio-group/tp-yt-paper-radio-button[1]/div[1]'
report_button_spam = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, report_button_spam)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", report_button_spam)

report_button_send = '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/tp-yt-paper-dialog/yt-report-form-modal-renderer/div/yt-button-renderer[2]/a/tp-yt-paper-button'
report_button_send = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, report_button_send)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", report_button_send)

popup_button_done = '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/tp-yt-paper-dialog[2]/yt-confirm-dialog-renderer/div[2]/div[2]/yt-button-renderer[3]/a/tp-yt-paper-button'
popup_button_done = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, popup_button_done)))
print(popup_button_done.text)
```